# Why am I missing "secret"?

Tags: node.js, cookies

Decided to use `cookie-parser` to sign a cookie, and receive

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Secret string must be
> provided.

**Original MyController.js**

```
const secureOptions = { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'Strict', secure: true };
res.cookie('MyCookie', 'yummy', secureOptions);
```

**Updated server.js**

```
// add followings for cookie-parser and keygrip.
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const keyGrip = require("keygrip");
const keyList = ['free text 1', 'free text 2'];
const keysForCookie = keyGrip(keyList, 'sha256');
app.use(cookieParser(keysForCookie));  // add cookieParser middleware to handle cookies using keysForCookie, should be in effect throughout.
```

**Updated MyController.js**

```
const secureOptions = { ..., signed: true };
res.cookie('MyCookie', 'yummy', secureOptions); // error here
```

Some answers mentioned `cookie-session` or `express-session`, but they are not listed at `cookie-parser` sites as dependency. Following got the same err:

```
const secureOptions = { ..., signed: true, secret: 'free text' };
res.cookie('MyCookie', 'yummy', secureOptions); // error here
```

Comment: You have to combine with `cookie-session` to make it configurable with `keygrip`

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me, `cookie-parser` is for reading only, not signing/writing.